# How should tag pages be treated from an SEO point of view?

Tags: seo, tags, page, seo-audit

How should tag pages be treated from an SEO point of view? We have tag pages on our website.

What's the best SEO practice for tag pages, similar to existing recommendations that we use for 404 pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag pages vary a lot in quality because you may or may not have many posts tagged.     Because of this, tag pages need careful attention for SEO purposes.    They can really lower the quality score of your site if users are landing on tag pages without much content listed.

Even tag pages that have five or ten posts listed on them are not usually going to be high quality landing pages.   Unless you write content specifically for them, they don't have any content on them that isn't found on the post pages.

My SEO recommendations for tag pages are:

- Use a meta robots noindex tag on any tag page with fewer than 5 posts listed
- Use software than gives you the ability to add content to tag pages.  (This site has tag wiki text, for example)

Comment: liked your second recommendation